# Inserting text area anywhere on page removes all other content

Tags: html, css, textarea

I have no idea what is going on. I have a page that has several divs hidden by javascript. depending which link you click, a different div shows up. It works great, until I try to put a textarea anywhere on the page. I started making a basic contact form...two inputs, a textarea and a submit button in one of the hidden divs. When I refreshed the site, all that's left is my background image. All of my other content (logo, menu) disappears. I removed the textarea and everything was back. I tried putting a text area in other parts of the page with the same result -- all that's left is the background image. Anyone have any advice?

here is the code I'm using to hide the divs...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

var $allContentDivs = $('#infocontent div').hide(); // Hide All Content Divs

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#link1').trigger('click');
});

$('#linkwrapper a').click(function(){
    var $contentDiv = $("#" + this.id + "content");

        $allContentDivs.hide(); // Hide All Divs
        $contentDiv.show(); // Show Div


    return false;        
  });
});

</script>
```

This is where I want to put a textarea:

```
<div class="modal" id="link4content">
    <font class="bigger">Будь ласка, напиши нам!<font>
    <form method="POST" action="mail.php">
      <p>ім'я<input type="text" name="name" /></p>
      <p>email <input type="text" name="email" /></p>
      <p>питання і коментарія
      </p>
      <textarea name="message" />
    </form>
  </div>
```

Comment: We also have no idea what is going on — until you post some code :)

Comment: Can you share your code and reproduce it in a fiddle?  http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: This will get closed unless you post a fiddle, some code or a link ASAP

Comment: As a side note, the `font` tag is deprecated as of ***HTML 4.01*** and removed in ***HTML 5***. Also the closing `<font>` tag should be `</font>`. I believe too that `<textarea />` is not a self closing tag and should instead be `<textarea></textarea>`. Just a few things right away that may cause problems.

Comment: Ah, thanks. adding the separate closing tag for <textarea> did it. Amateur coder problems :)

Comment: @steele Awesome glad to hear it. I'll add that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues that should be addressed to help validate your markup.

1. The font tag is deprecated as of HTML 4.01 and removed in HTML 5. You should consider using CSS for this.
2. The closing <font> tag should be </font>.
3. The <textarea /> tag is not a self closing tag and should instead be <textarea></textarea>.

Fixing these minor issues should cure the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a static HTML page? If you try to generate it by a server-side script, it is possible that the script fails due to an error and outputs only the beginning of the page. This should be clear when looking at source in browser (usually opened via Ctrl + U).

Try using Firebug (or something similar) to view how your browser parses the page.